# struct.error: required argument is not an integer Python

Tags: python, struct, wave

I am trying to take a wave, filter out some frequencies and then save it to a .wav file.

I keep getting errors with the struct.pack

This is where my frequencies variable comes from

```
data = wav_file.readframes(num_samples)
wav_file.close()
data = struct.unpack('{n}h'.format(n=num_samples), data)
data = np.array(data)
data = np.array(data)
data_fft = np.fft.fft(data)
frequencies = np.abs(data_fft)

frequency1 = np.delete(frequencies, np.argmax(frequencies))
frequency1_ = np.delete(frequency1, np.argmax(frequency1))
frequency2 = np.delete(frequency1_, np.argmax(frequency1_))
frequency2_ = np.delete(frequency2, np.argmax(frequency2))
frequency3 = np.delete(frequency2_, np.argmax(frequency2_))
new_frequency = frequency3
```

I know all of that above is correct

```
num_samples=770241
inverse = np.fft.ifft(new_frequency)
fdata = struct.pack('{n}h'.format(n=num_samples), *inverse)
outfile=wave.open('filtered.wav', 'w')
outfile.setnchannels(channels)
outfile.setsampwidth(swidth)
outfile.setframerate(rate)
outfile.writeframes(fdata)
```

I can't seem to get this stuct.pack function to work no matter what I try.

If I take away the * I get this error struct.error: pack expected 770241 items for packing (got 1)

And if I include it I get struct.error: required argument is not an integer

Comment: Unless I'm missing a step, `np.fft.ifft()` produces an array of complex numbers. You have to convert those to integers before packing them as format type `h`.

Comment: inverse2 = np.abs(inverse) I added this and I get the same error

Comment: `np.abs`, given an array of complex numbers, returns an array of floats.

Comment: `np.abs()` converts from complex to float, you would still need to convert that to integers, e.g. `inverse3 = inverse2.astype(np.int64)`.